# Is there a `data.table` representation of sparse matrices / objects?

Tags: r, data.table, sparse-matrix

I want to work in the `data.table` framework for various reasons not contained in this post. Does `data.table` have a sparse representation for indicator matrices, ala the `Matrix` package?

```
library(Matrix)
library(data.table)

set.seed(123409L)

ints <- sample.int(2L, 1e6, replace=T, prob= c(0.9, 0.1)) - 1

m <- Matrix(ints, ncol= 1000)
dt <- data.table(matrix(ints, ncol= 1000))

pryr::object_size(m) # 1.22 MB
pryr::object_size(dt) # 8.1 MB
```

Assume in the actual use case I have closer to `6e8` elements, where growth is hypothetically unbounded.

Apologies in advance if this question has already been answered. I'm happy for it to be flagged as a duplicate; but I didn't find a duplicate via search.

Comment: Well, `mdt = as.data.table(which(matrix(ints, ncol=1000)==1, arr.ind = TRUE))` is another representation, somewhat smaller (probably only because I'm throwing out the `@x` piece seen in `m`). With it stored that way, you won't have access to all the Matrix functions designed to play nice with dgCMatrix objects, though, so it might not be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

As @Frank suggested in his comment, you can represent a sparse matrix efficiently in a `data.table` by storing non-zero elements along with their indices as individual observations, i.e., in triplet form:

```
m2 <- as(m, "dgTMatrix")
dt2 <- data.table(i=m2@i+1, j=m2@j+1, value=m2@x)

pryr::object_size(dt2) # 1.62 MB
```

this `data.table` can also be constructed from `dt`:

```
dt2 <- melt(copy(dt)[,i:=.I], id.vars="i"
    )[value>0][,j:=as.integer(variable)][,variable:=NULL]
```